# horizantolly algin elements inside a well

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align elements inside a well, the image's location changed, causing the well to get bigger.I think this question [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div-with-width-100)  helped me position stores' details in the correct place. But the image is causing the problem.

```
<% @stores.each do |store| %>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="well">
         <%= link_to image_tag(root_url + "/images/" + store.filename, size: "100x100", alt: store.filename), store %>
           <div id="inner">
            <h3><%=store.name%></h3>
            <h4><%=store.foodType%></h4>
            <p><%=store.description%></p>
            <% if current_user != store.user %>
            <%= rating_for store, "overall", :enable_half => true,:half_show => true,:disable_after_rate => false %>
            <% end %>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </div> 
    <% end %>
```

I feel like I need a tag specifically for my image.But I'm not quite sure how to set it.

bootstrap.css

```
   #inner {
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
   }
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just give `text-align: center;` to `.well` will make all elements horizontally center.

```
.well{
     text-align: center;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2g6j7k7/)**

Comment: This is good, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I need my image in the far left of the well. Then some space. Then a store description :)

Comment: @A1X You can give `margin-right: 20px;` to `img`. Or you can increase and decrease as per your requirement.

Comment: Checkout my screenshoot please. This what I've originally :)

Comment: @A1X So, what you want now? It is not center ?

Comment: I want to get ride of the space on the top. The well is bigger than needed :0. The image location is causing the well to get bigger.

Comment: @A1X If you want to remove space top from image then give `vertical-align: top;` to `img` and if you want to remove top space from `.inner` div then remove padding. like: `padding: 0 50px 50px;` to `inner`. https://jsfiddle.net/b2g6j7k7/2/